# cannot find symbol String token = task.getResult().getToken();

Tags: android, firebase, notifications

when I add this code in my MainActivity, I got this error. where has problem?

```
// Firebase message
        FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            return;
                        }
                        if( task.getResult() == null)
                            return;
                        // Get new Instance ID token
                        String token = task.getResult().getToken();
                        // Log and toast
                        Log.i("MainActivity","token "+token);
                    }
                });
```

why cannnot getToken()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try add object in your listener and task like this.

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<InstanceIdResult> task) {
        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
            Log.i("MainActivity", "getInstanceId failed");
            return;
        }

        // Get new Instance ID token
        String token = task.getResult().getToken();
        Log.i("MainActivity","token "+token);
        
    }
});
```

Comment: May I ask question? how can send the message to the Author when the user reply the comment?